# Floating divs with fixed top position

Tags: css, css-float

I have an HTML "toolbar" containing a number of widgets arranged horizontally. Each item is represented by a `div` in the source document:

```
<div id="widget1" />
<div id="widget2" />
<div id="widget3" />
```

I position the divs using `float: left`. The problem is that I also want them to be pinned to the top of the toolbar so that they don't wrap around if the user reduces the width of the window. Instead, I just want them to overflow horizontally (with the overflow hidden) so that the behavior is like that of a real toolbar.

In other words, I want something like `position: fixed` but only for the vertical coordinate. Horizontally they should be positioned one after another in a row. Is there any way to do this with CSS?

**Update** Here's the real HTML I'm using. The `divs`s with `class="row"` are the ones that should appear as widgets in the toolbar, arranged horizontally in a single row.

```
<div class="row" id="titleRow">
  <span class="item"> <img src="../images/logo.png" height="26" /> </span>
  <span class="item" id="title">Title</span>
  <span class="item" id="close" onclick="window.close();"> close </span>
</div>

<div class="row" id="menuRow">
  <span class="item"> <ul id="menu"></ul> </span>
</div>

<div class="row" id="searchRow">
</div>

<div class="row" id="pageRow">
  <span class="item" id="page-related-data"> Page-related data: </span>
</div>
```

Comment: CAn you provide some more markup and css so I can take a closer look. Thanks.

Comment: try with this    #widget1{ position:absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-450px; top:0px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `float: left;` try `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`. Then set `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element. See http://jsfiddle.net/rt9sS/1/ for an example.

Note `inline-block` has some issues. It's white space aware (so white space around elements in the HTML will be visible in the document). It also has limited support in IE6/7, although you can work around that by giving the element layout, e.g. `.oldie .widget { display:inline; zoom:1; }`. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock for more.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had tried most of that but was missing `whitespace: no-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, wanted to add a simple jquery answer for those that run across it.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$("#keep-in-place").css("top",$(document).scrollTop()+"px");
});
```

To make higher or lower on page simply add to $(document).scrollTop()

Works for me